# Fumes from soldering

Tags: soldering, safety

I breathe alot of soldering fumes and i don't have anything that is used to remove this fumes while soldering, is it really bad for my health? How it affects the brain and other organs?

Comment: I need a small additional answer, does it affect the brain??

Comment: Thanks @PlasmaHH , didn't see this until after I responded.

Comment: If you know how to use google, there are lots of options. Most of the options have an activated carbon filter to grab most of the stuff out of the air. https://www.google.com/search?q=solder+fume+removal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/19086/3288)

Answer (score 3):

Soldering fumes can be dangerous in several ways. The most obvious is if you're using solder that contains lead. Lead fumes are known to cause health issues, particularly related to reproduction. Another source of harmful fumes is from the flux, which has been known to cause:

- Occupational Asthma
- Chronic Bronchitis
- Chemical Hypersensitivity
- Chest Pain
- Headaches & Dizziness
- Eye and Nose Irritation
- Skin diseases

One more possible source of harmful fumes is if your iron touches something that it shouldn't, such as certain forms of plastic. That could also release harmful chemicals (I once hit a patch of superglue I didn't know was there and it burned my eyes for an hour).

It's not worth the risk. Set up in a well-ventilated area and use a fume extractor (even a homemade one created from a PC fan and a plastic bag) to suck the fumes away from your work area. Otherwise, yes--You could have health issues including reproductive harm, respiratory problems, and headaches/dizziness.

I suggest reading the following: http://www.elexp.com/Images/Health_Hazards.PDF