Is it necessary to have a hood if soldering with lead-free solder?
When the solder is lead (lead is not excreted by the body and is harmful), then an exhaust hood is needed.
If you solder with rosin, gel rosin, LTI-120 (soldering flux LTI 120 consists of 25% rosin and 75% alcohol solution with
active ingredients) and lead-free solder (SnCu, Sn97Cu3, E Sn100 C, others,) is it still needed?

What is the boiling point of lead? Does your soldering iron get that hot?

@SteKulov, As I understand it, although lead has a melting point of 1749 degrees, approximately 0.5% simply evaporates, especially since in the solder tin begins to melt, dissolving the lead, increasing the amount of lead in the air

I don't understand this comment about lead evaporation. Evaporation depends on the vapor pressure, not melting point. And I don't see why solution with tin has an effect on evaporation. A reference is definitely needed for this.

You just melt the lead or lead alloy to solder things - be they electrical terminals or copper for plumbing. There are various grades of solder and flux. Breathing anything other than clean air demands some type of filter or mask as per the health and safety regulations in many countries. Ok, some are much more lax than others....

@SolarMike, , strange, I couldn’t find another article about lead release percentages, but about not using it: here’s one of them

@NikolaiVorobiev The boiling point of lead is 1749 °C. Please make sure to specify the units, as quite a few people who use this site use other units.

Until you can prove the vapours are safe, assume they are unhealthy. https://aircleansystems.com/application-notes/Soldering

Some references refer to lead oxide in the fumes. Not sure if it's particulates or vapor. The vapor pressure of elemental lead at normal electronic soldering temperatures should be very low. This question could use an authoritative reference, if one exists. But in any case, I agree with those who say the flux fumes alone are reason enough to avoid inhaling them as much as possible. Soldering all day is also different from making a couple quick touch-up joints.

@SolarMike Yet it's fine to deliberately and repeatedly inhale the fumes and chemicals from burning vegetation if the government gets a cut of the profits.

@NikolaiVorobiev  Please see my 2011 SEEE answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/19086/3288 (and 7 other answers) which cover this subject in some detail for leaded and to a lesser extent unleaded solder. Unleaded could be largely considered a lead-free subset of leaded when looking at my answer. I also provide a numbr of references which relate equally to lead based and lead free solders.

We had this topic discussed here many times. It has nothing to do with lead what-so-ever since the temperature of a solder iron is nowhere near hot enough to vaporize any of the metals involved - in which case you would be melting the components as well. Soldering is not welding.
Whenever you do any form of professional soldering, you always need a  solder fume extractor, which are devices that come in various shapes and sizes. Often it is a hose of some kind which you fix near the solder area, which vacuums out the harmful gasses away from your face and into some manner of filter.
Just using some DIY fan is not recommended. Holding your breath is not recommended.
The sole purpose of this is to extract vaporized flux and other chemicals from the solder core. These gasses are harmful and can cause various allergies and respiratory problems. RoHS solder is more unhealthy since it melts at approximately 30°C higher temperature than leaded solder, which in turn means more vaporized flux. RoHS was sadly never meant to protect the PCBA assembly operator from chemicals.
Additionally, touching the plastic parts of some connector by accident with your tip happens now and then, even to veterans. There's no healthy gasses coming out of that either.
It is particularly unhealthy to do repair work on PCBA which were covered in conformal coating, glue, silicone or similar. Then a fume extractor is not enough, you need to do such work inside a chemistry hood. Remove as much of the chemicals as possible with isopropyl, then use plenty of external flux. And don't use your finest solder tip...
Soldering is an industrial process, so you need to wash your hands after soldering. Lead is only harmful if you manage to get it in your mouth. And for this reason you shouldn't do soldering in the living areas of your home, getting solder splatter on the floor where small children or pets might be exposed to it.

Will be the soap after soldering enough to protect your hands?

@NikolaiVorobiev If you get melted solder splatter on your hands you'll notice it, as it burns like ****. Cooled solder splatter in the form of balls tend to not stick around but fall off thanks to gravity. But generally you have to be a bit clumsy to get solder splatter at all, since during ideal soldering, the solder should never even touch the tip (utopia). When soldering harder stuff like coaxial/RF connectors for example, the tip can't touch the solder or you'll create a mess which can't get fully removed from for example a gold plated surface.

I mean, if I already got my hands dirty

Anyway the key here is forget about the lead, vaporized flux is the very real health concern which needs to be dealt with and everything else is of peripheral note. I've met some 20+ soldering veterans with various asthma, allergies and lung problems. I never met one who suffered from lead poisoning.

so for protecting from flux we have some variants: 1. ibb.co/8gFSb3t (they say it is fume, but I am not sure of it) 2. ibb.co/bPTZj57 + ibb.co/6Z0t9DZ ( Xiaomi Hepa filter)+ ibb.co/9YbF3wC (to help smoke extractor)3. ibb.co/hfp9p7K. Right?

@NikolaiVorobiev Only the last one seems to be truly professional, the smoke needs to be removed from where you are working, just having some fan show it through a filter is questionable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

One could argue that the exhaust is even more important in the case of lead-free solder than in the case of leaded solder. The flux used with lead-free solder tends to be worse for you than that used with leaded solder, and the fumes are 100% flux--even when using leaded solder, there is no lead in the fumes.
The possibility of lead poisoning comes primarily from lead residue on the operator's hands, not from inhalation. If not washed off, the lead can get into food or rubbed into eyes. Note also that metallic lead, as found in solder, is not as toxic as lead compounds as found in lead paint or leaded gasoline, and most of it will pass right through your body--though it's still not harmless, so do be sure to wash it off. The reason lead solder is banned in many applications is less due to risk to the operators and more due to environmental hazards; lead that ends up in landfills or otherwise discarded will naturally convert over time to more toxic forms.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Probably not, Lead has a boiling point of 1750C and not much if any vaporizes at 230C (typical soldering temp). That being said it isn't zero. But you probably get more by eating fish than through the air. (I couldn't find any resources on how much lead get's vaporized, but with the amounts and similar studies I've done on broken CFL's and mercury you get more by eating fish with mercury, which is about the same molecular weight. Salmon can give you 10-160ug of lead in one fish dinner. I'm willing to be that if you are heating lead, you'll get less than 10ug by breathing.)
But that isn't why you need a fume extractor (usually fume hoods are not used, extractors with an activated carbon filter are enough)
The reason why you have a filter is for halides which are halogens like chlorine, bromine, iodine, or fluorine that are found in fluxes. These are way worse for you to breathe in but not as toxic as lead.
So use a fume extractor (or hood)

So fume extractor or hood can cope with both lead and flux fumes?

Activated carbon catches lead

But I need to change it, right?

Or does the filter not need to be changed over time, and what is the difference between HAKKO-400 and HAKKO-493?

All filters need to be changed depending on use

How to understand when I should change them?

Consult the manufacturer. I usually change air filters when they look dirty

Okey, and what is the difference between HAKKO-400 and HAKKO-493?

So what is the difference?
